# JMeter - Append Timestamp to the File name

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am writing some data into a file. Please find below the snippet in JSR223 Post processor.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
f = new File("C:/Users/503289283/Downloads/Service_Start.csv")
```

Filename needs to be appended with the Timestamp. Tried using ${__time(dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss,)} and Date.getTime(). It doesn't work. Not sure if am doing it right.

Kindly help.

Regards,
Ajith

I tried with

```
new File('C:/Users/503289283/Downloads/Service_Start_ ' + new Date().format('dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss') + '.csv')
```

It throws an error.
Log:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\503289283\Downloads\Service_Start_ 14-03-2022_10:13:12.csv (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

whereas

```
new File("C:/Users/503289283/Downloads/Service_Start.csv")
```

works perfectly.

Is something missed here? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
new File('C:/Users/503289283/Downloads/Service_Start_ ' + new Date().format('dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss') + '.csv')
```

[image]

More information:

- [Groovy JDK Enhancements - Date](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)